# How to get a list of offline users in Joomla 3?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

As the title says I'm looking for a solution to fetch a list of offline users of an specific user group. Is there any workaround?

Actually I am customizing a module and am in need of showing offline users on front-end. I'd greatly appreciate if someone shed me a light.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you show what you've tried already (code snippet or sample of what you've attempted).

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question. You can run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `#__users`  WHERE `lastVisitDate` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

The above query assumes that a user who logged in more than an hour ago is now logged out. The thing is, you cannot have 100% accuracy here because a user can login for 5 minutes and then leave and a user can be logged in for 16 hours non-stop. The above query, however, will yield good, appoximate results. You can always tweak the interval time (for example, changing it to `INTERVAL 2 HOUR`) to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attention itoctopus.

I finally managed to get this done by the following function :

```
public static function getOfflineUserNames($params)
{
    $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select ($db->quoteName('a.username'))
        ->from('#__users AS a');

    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__session AS m ON m.username = a.username')
          ->where('m.username IS NULL');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    return (array) $db->loadObjectList();
}
```